# Making translations based on a database

Tags: c#, database, user-interface

I am being completely hypothetical at this point, but since I am new to c#, I wanted to ask the opinion of others to see what the better ways of approaching this might be. At this point, I have a program that is looking for tags and comparing them to a master list of tags. However, at the moment, the tags are read and register a 24 character string. The strings are fine for the program, but I would like to have the output reference a database with a translator for each of these strings, so that when the final program outputs the tags that have been found and the ones that are missing, the tags have appropriate names along with them, and not just a complicated string of characters.

Since I am new, I would just like to see if anyone can give me ideas on how to handle this and possibly point me in the right direction to get started.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should look into using resource files instead. .NET has a lot of built in functionalities having to do with internationalization and .resx files. Check this out: [Walkthrough: Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @Renan I read most of that article, but could this really be used to associate different tag numbers with specific things such as types of food or brands of soda? I don't exactly know what I'm going to use this for, but the idea would be to have the program scan for a bunch of tag numbers, and once it decides which ones are missing, the user is notified with an actual name and not soda brand 2984978327283740872374087208374. The user could always translate in the end, but that would be too much of a hassle.